# Confused about the use of [ ] to index a list of colours

Tags: r

I'm running and example of the book "Beckerman, A. P., & Petchey, O. L. (2012). Getting Started with R. An Introduction for Biologist. Oxford, Reino U nido: Oxford University Press."

The example is this

```r
# plot window 
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
# the plot
plot(EGGS ~ DENSITY, data = limp, pch = 19, cex = 1.5, 
    col = c("Black","Red")[limp$SEASON], 
    xlab = list("Density", cex = 1.2), 
    ylab = list("Eggs Produced", cex = 1.2))
# add a legend 
legend(35,3,legend = c("spring","summer"),  
     col = c("black", "red"), pch = c(19, 19))
```

But if I include the `limp$SEASON` R doesn't print the data on the plot.

This is the data

```
structure(list(DENSITY = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 
45L, 45L, 45L), SEASON = c("spring", "spring", "spring", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "spring", "spring", "spring", "summer", "summer", 
"summer", "spring", "spring", "spring", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
"spring", "spring", "spring", "summer", "summer", "summer"), 
    EGGS = c(2.875, 2.625, 1.75, 2.125, 1.5, 1.875, 2.6, 1.866, 
    2.066, 0.867, 0.933, 1.733, 2.23, 1.466, 1, 1.267, 0.467, 
    0.7, 1.4, 1.022, 1.177, 0.711, 0.356, 0.711), season = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("spring", "summer"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55d2263c37f0>)
```

Comment: could we have a *reproducible* example? How did you get the `limp` data set into R?

Answer (score 4):

@DanY's answer gives good general context, but the likely *specific* reason that this example is not working is that it will only work if `limp$SEASON` is an integer vector *or a factor*. Prior to R version 4.0 (i.e., when this example was written), the default for importing data was that character columns would automatically be transformed into factors (`stringsAsFactors = TRUE`). That is no longer the default, so you probably need to specify `limp$SEASON <- factor(limp$SEASON)` before trying the plotting code.

Comment: Thanks a lot... thats the reason, now flows perfectly

Comment: OK. If this solves your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common technique to color points on scatterplots created with the `plot()` function in R.

The general idea is:

```
color_vec[integer_vec]
```

For example, suppose `x` and `y` are length-5 vectors so that `plot(x, y)` creates a scatterplot of 5 points.  Let's suppose we want to color some of those points red and some blue.  We could define `color_vec` and `integer_vec` as:

```
color_vec <- c("red", "blue")
integer_vec <- c(2, 2, 1, 2, 1)
```

Then the code `color_vec[integer_vec]` produces:

```
color_vec[integer_vec]
## "blue" "blue" "red"  "blue" "red"
```

Adding it to the plot command then produces a scatterplot of 5 points where the third and fifth are colored red, the others blue:

```
plot(x, y, col=color_vec[integer_vec])
```

Note that `integer_vec` is commonly a factor variable in the dataframe containing `x` and `y` so that each of the colors in `color_vec` is assigned to a level of the factor variable.

Comment: very useful post thaks a lot